# windows can not shutdown after installing ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, shutdown

I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus n46 running windows 8.1. after a problem with dual boot both of them and solving it by boot-repair,I have faced a new problem that in windows I can not shut down the laptop,the screen for moment gets black and again its going back on log on window.
how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's not ubuntu problem ,but windows, so try doing this on windows:

run cmd(with admin rights)

type:

```
 sfc/scannow
```

hope it helps.